# How to get specific rows in Hbase?

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase

My rowKeys in HBase like this;

```
a1s1
a1s2
a1s3
a2s1
a3s1
a3s2
...
```

I want to get only these data;

```
a1s1
a2s1
a3s1
```

But when I run thise query; **scan 't1', {STARTROW=>'a1s1', ENDROW=>'a4s1'}**

It gives me;

```
a1s1
a1s2
a1s3
a2s1
a3s1
```

But I don't want to get **a1s2 and a1s3**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use STARTROW-ENDROW and another filter with RegexStringComparator. If you use only start-end row filter, hbase performs this     filtration for each character in your rowkey. Because rowkey is not numeric. In Hbase shell you can try this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RegexStringComparator

scan 't1', {STARTROW => 'a1s1', ENDROW => 'a4s1', FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),RegexStringComparator.new("s1$"))}
```

Comment: In this solution, doesn't Hbase do full scan table?

Comment: No it doesn't. It scans between start-end row key. For example i tried in hbase shell with start-end rowkey and without it. With start-end rowkey it took 0.0950 seconds and without it took 41.3580 seconds. So we can say if you perform filter with start-end rowkey, the scan operation wont perform full scan.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you want to get the row key starting with "a*" and ending with "s1".

So either you can use below:

```
 scan 't1', { ENDROW=>'s1'}
```

Or

```
scan 't1', {STARTROW=>'a', ENDROW=>'s1'}
```

Another option is using regexString:

```
scan 't1', {FILTER => "RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:*s1')"}
```

Comment: What error are you getting with that? You can also try with RowFilter

Comment: The first two solutions here won't work because `STARTROW` and `ENDROW` are used to define the prefix of the first and last rows in the scan, and not the start/end positions of a specific row.

Comment: Well, Can I use PrefixFilter with Start and EndRow?

Comment: If `STARTROW` == `ENDROW`, it seems random access. It will be slower as the range between them increases. `FILTER` slowly loops all over the rows...